# URL rewrite in IIS add character

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I need a temporary fix by adding a 0 in the URL between 2 slashes '//' until a permanent fix is done.
Here is a sample URL and below is the rewrite rule that I did but it doesn't work.

https://example.com/PortalWebService/api/List/getpdf/10/1//16/en-ca/

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>       
     <rule name="Rewrite URL add 0 between //" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="false">
         <match url="*1//*" />
           <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}1/0/{R:2}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
         </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try a small tweak to your `match url` - turn those asterisks into match groups so that URL Rewrite knows how to capture and replace their contents:

```
<match url="^https://(.*)1//(.*)" />
```

Comment: Hi Adil, thanks but your solution didn't work. Do I need to recycle the app pool each time I add a rule or it should work right away?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your original rule is correct.

You could try to put the complete url in this way:

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="https://{R:1}1/0/{R:2}"
```

Only for a try: If you use the action type "Redirect" is it working?